# How can i find users location in java

Tags: java, mysql, jquery

How to get users location from his **IP** address

And what are the free  Java APIs that I can make use of to get the location of the user.

Comment: check GeoGoogle http://geo-google.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: If this is an answer I would create an answer and allow others to upvote/accept etc.

Comment: possible duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257170/how-to-get-city-name-based-on-ip-address-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is "geolocation". I've been using

http://www.maxmind.com

for 10 years now. They also have a [free service](http://www.maxmind.com/en/geolite).

Comment: hii ingo first of i would like to thank u for replying and actually we need a free service only but is that reliable and good  how to download their database and integrate it with my java application? plz reply

Comment: The second link in my answer is a free service.