# Google maps ip address list

Tags: google-maps

I have looked but cannot find a way or answer to load a list of ip addresses into google maps. 
So say you have 20 ip addresses and want to load those onto google maps via api call when the webpage loads...is that possible?
I can supply the text list of ip addresses for the api to grab upon load. does this make sense?

Comment: > "does this make sense?" No.  What are you trying to do with this list of IP addresses?

Comment: Im trying to display their location on a map. So basically I have a list of IP's and just want to show the location on the map. This wouldnt be a "live" list of like users hitting a website, rather a list of previous IPs over time. make sense?

Comment: IP addresses don't have location information.  There are APIs to estimate their location, but not from Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting geolocation from ip address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050097/getting-geolocation-from-ip-address/14050303#14050303)

Comment: Yeah I know this. I know you can use maxmind. I was hoping for some native ip to geolocation built into google maps. I was just thinking I missed this functionality in the api guide. or there was an easier way they taking ip's converting to geo lan/lng but even after that can I import the geo lan/lng from a list to display on the map?

Comment: BTW 64. is a country etc. 10. is private(wouldnt show on map obviously, so there are basic ranges for countries I could use. Im not looking to put in someones house. Just country or state..that type of info. mostly country

Comment: On maps.google.com? (No) Or using the Google Maps API v3? (Yes)

Comment: Ok just so I know for sure. the GM API v3 yes I can import a list of lat/longitude, and it will display? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but I was researching the same question, so here goes...

For a simple (but manual) tool, you can use [BatchGeo](http://batchgeo.com/) to load a list of IP addresses, and have the system geolocate them. The results show up on an embeddable Google Map. As far as I know, they have no API support.

A possible automated way would be to use an external api for the Geolocation ([FreeGeoIP](http://freegeoip.net/) comes to mind), and pass the latitude/longtitude list to Google via the Google API.